# Change state of one component from another using bus pattern in Vue.js 2

Tags: javascript, vuejs2

My main component has a loader that blocks the view if something loads on any child component. I would like to be able to send command 'load is finished' to the parent component from a child component.

The main component has:

```
 data: function() {
            return {
                isLoading : false
            }
        }
```

that should be changed.

I've tried to use bus pattern specified in the doc (https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/components.html#Non-Parent-Child-Communication)

I have created `event-bus.js` in the root with `export const EventBus = new Vue();` content

Now in the main component, I'd like to subscribe to the event and change the state, but if I write:

```
 var eventBus = require("./event-bus.js").EventBus;
    eventBus.$on('isLoadingChanged', receivedLoading => {
        isLoading = receivedLoading;
    });
```

I receive `isLoading is not defined`. How do I change the state?

Please note that I'm using `vue` file. My whole main component looks like this:

```
<template>
    <div>
        <div class="globalLoader" v-if="isLoading">
            <GridLoader></GridLoader>
            <!--<p>Loading...</p>-->
        </div>
        <content-component></content-component>
    </div>
</template>

<script>
   
    var GridLoader= require('vue-spinner/dist/vue-spinner.min').GridLoader;
    
    var eventBus = require("./event-bus.js").EventBus;
    eventBus.$on('isLoadingChanged', receivedLoading => {
        isLoading = receivedLoading;
    });

    var d = {
        components: {
            'content-component': ...,
            'GridLoader': GridLoader
        },

        data: function() {
            return {
                isLoading : false
            }
        }
    };

    export default d;
</script>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So the thing is you are declaring the `isLoading` property inside the component's data

To be able to access that property you need to use `this.isLoading`

What I would recommend is to declare the handling of the event inside one of the Component's lifecycle methods.

The code should look as follows:

```
.... 
<script>

var GridLoader= require('vue-spinner/dist/vue-spinner.min').GridLoader;

var eventBus = require("./event-bus.js").EventBus;

var d = {
    components: {
        'content-component': ...,
        'GridLoader': GridLoader
    },

    data: function() {
        return {
            isLoading : false
        }
    },
    created: function() {
      eventBus.$on('isLoadingChanged', receivedLoading => {
        this.isLoading = receivedLoading;
      });
    }
};

export default d;
</script>
```